# Lazysizes.min.js implementation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, lazy-loading

We're attempting to implement  (https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/tree/master) on https://berkshireblanket.com.

But after following all directions, the implementation will not work. When I run a check using DevTools, it outputs as false:

```
typeof($("img").lazyload) === "function"
```

I'm at a loss, and I'm not sure if we're missing something either within the script or within the HTML.

Here's a look at our HTML to show how it's currently being implemented:

[image: HTML and liquid implementation of lazyload (HTML and liquid code pasted below)]

```
<div class="product-main-images {% if section.settings.thumbnails == 'bottom' %}desktop-12{% else %}desktop-10{% endif %} tablet-6 mobile-3" tabindex="0">
    <div class="product-image-container" style="padding-bottom: {{ product_image_box_ratio_max }};" >
    {% for image in product.images %}
    {% assign image_box_ratio = image.height | append: ".0" | times: 1 | divided_by: image.width | times: 100 | append: "%" %}
    {% assign img_url = image | img_url: '1x1' | replace: '_1x1.', '_{width}x.' %}

    <div class="product-main-image {% if forloop.first %}selected{% endif %}" data-image-id="{{ image.id }}">
        <a class="product-fancybox" rel="product-images"  href="{{ image | img_url: '2400x' }}" tabindex="-1">
            <img id="{{ product.id }}" class="product__image lazyload"
            src="{{ image | product_img_url: '300x' }}"
            data-src="{{ img_url }}"
            data-sizes="auto"
            data-zoom-src="{{ image | img_url: '2400x' }}"
            alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
        </a>
        <noscript>
            <img id="{{ product.id }}" class="product-main-image lazyload" src="{{ featured_image | product_img_url: '800x' }}" alt='{{ image.alt | escape }}'/>
        </noscript>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Please let me know if I can clarify anything, or provide further examples of our current implementation.

Thanks!

Comment: What are these two lines for? `{% assign image_box_ratio = image.height | append: ".0" | times: 1 | divided_by: image.width | times: 100 | append: "%" %}
    {% assign img_url = image | img_url: '1x1' | replace: '_1x1.', '_{width}x.' %}`

Comment: Good question! Unfortunately, I'm not sure.

We previously had a developer on our team who implemented the custom theme we currently use. I'm not sure if these were liquid lines he added in, or if they were part of the theme already. I believe it may be an attempt to make the image box responsive?

Comment: From what I can see, lazyloader is working fine. `$("img").lazyload` looks like a local function and hence you are seeing 'false' error when you check in the debugger. Any specific reason you feel lazyloader isn't working?

Comment: Upon page load, the Network tab of Chrome DevTools shows all of the images loading even before the scroll event. We've also gotten pinged on several page load time audits as not lazyloading on our Collection pages, as well as our Product pages.

Comment: lazysizes script file is placed at the bottom of your theme and hence your images are loaded even before the script is loaded. Move it to the head section.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to change `src` to `data-src`:

```
<img id="{{ product.id }}" class="product-main-image lazyload" data-src="{{ featured_image | product_img_url: '800x' }}" alt='{{ image.alt | escape }}'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

install lazysizes, then add class "lazyload" to all images and iframes and in the img tag make sure to change "src" to "data-src"

Comment: You need to elaborate this answer. It does not add anything helpful compared to previous answer.